# merge tuple in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have two sets of tuples and I want to inner join them by first element and merge other parts into one tuple, wondering how to implement this in Pig on Hadoop?

Input two tuple sets,

```
1,(1,2)
2,(2,3)

1,(b,c,b,c)
2,(c,d,c,d)
```

Expected output,

```
1,(1,2,b,c,b,c)
2,(2,3,c,d,c,d)
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thought worth contemplating ...

**Inputs :**

**dataA :**

```
1   (1,2)
2   (2,3)
```

**dataB:**

```
1   (b,c,b,c)
2   (c,d,c,d)
```

**Pig Script :**

```
A = LOAD 'dataA'  USING  PigStorage('\t') AS  (aid:long, atuple : tuple(af1:long, af2:long));
B = LOAD 'dataB'  USING  PigStorage('\t') AS  (bid:long, btuple : tuple(bf1:chararray, bf2:chararray, bf3:chararray, bf4:chararray));
C = JOIN A BY aid, B BY bid;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE aid AS id, FLATTEN(atuple) AS (af1:long, af2:long) , FLATTEN(btuple) AS (bf1:chararray, bf2:chararray, bf3:chararray, bf4:chararray);
E = FOREACH D GENERATE id, (af1..bf4);
DUMP E;
```

**Output : DUMP E :**

```
(1,(1,2,b,c,b,c))
(2,(2,3,c,d,c,d))
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but if the 2nd tuple of each row has variant number of elements, how do you handle?

Comment: @LinMa : If we are aware of max number of elements in a row then we can either declare aliases for all of them or we can access elements using $ notation. For eg : if max number of elements in tuple 1 is 2 and in tuple 2 is 100 then while deriving the tuple for alias E in the sample set use ($1..$103)